# Find the closest value for a certain year in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have this type of data:

```
iso3 year    UHC         cata10
AFG 2010    0.3551409   NA
AFG 2011    0.3496452   NA
AFG 2012    0.3468012   NA
AFG 2013    0.3567721   14.631331
AFG 2014    0.3647436   NA
AFG 2015    0.3717983   NA
AFG 2016    0.3855273   4.837534
AFG 2017    0.3948606   NA
AGO 2011    0.3250651   12.379809
AGO 2012    0.3400455   NA
AGO 2013    0.3397722   NA
AGO 2014    0.3385741   NA
AGO 2015    0.3521086   16.902584
AGO 2016    0.3636765   NA
AGO 2017    0.3764945   NA
```

and I would like to find the closest value to year 2012 and 2017 (+ ou - 2 years, i.e. for 2012 it can be 2010, 2011, 2013 or 2014 data) for cata10 variable. The output should be :

```
iso3year_UHC    UHC         year_cata   cata10   
AFG 2012        0.3468012   2013        14.631331
AFG 2017        0.3948606   2016        4.837534
AGO 2012        0.3400455   2011        12.379809
AGO 2017        0.3764945   2015        16.902584
```

**EDIT:** Note that I should have NA is there is no data 2 years before or after the reference year.

I have tried tones of commands since two days but could not manage to find a solution. Could you please advice on the type of commands to try?

Thank you very much,

N.

Comment: How are you creating `year_cata` column?

Comment: You may want to show one or two of your attempts, that we can see where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: I would if my attempts were at all meaningful.. I don't know which direction to take..I was thinking of transposing but it will not help..I was thinking of finding the latest year available using something like this: mutate(last_year_cata10 = ifelse(length(cata10[!is.na(cata10)])>0,max(year[!is.na(cata10)]),NA)) but it will not give me what i want..

Comment: Here is my code, I have just removed the NAs on both columns and create year_UHC and year_cata:        
  uhc_comb2 <- uhc_comb %>%
  mutate(flag=0) %>%
  mutate_cond(is.na(mean14re)&is.na(cata_tot_10_pop),flag=1) %>%
  filter(flag==0) %>%
  select(-flag) %>%
  rename(year_UHC = year) %>%
  mutate(year_cata = year_UHC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three approaches.  The first one is the clearest as it shows that the problem is really an aggregated and filtered self-join and directly models this and automatically handles the edge case mentioned in the comments without additional code. The second one uses a `lapply` loop to get the desired effect but it involves more tedious manipulation although it does have the advantage of zero package dependencies.  The last one gets around the fact that dplyr lacks complex self joins by performing a left join twice.

**1) sqldf** Using `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end perform a self join such that the difference in years is -2, -1, 1 or 2 and the iso3 codes are the same and cata10 is not NA in matching instance and among those rows we use `min(...)` to find the row having the minimum absolute difference in the year.  This uses the fact that SQLite has the feature that `min(...)` will cause the entire row to be returned that satisfies the minimizing condition. Finally take only the 2012 and 2017 rows.  The ability of SQL to directly model the constraints using a complex join allows us to directly model the requirements into code.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select 
      a.iso3year iso3year_UHC, 
      a.UHC, 
      substr(b.iso3year, 5, 8) year_cata, 
      b.cata10, 
      substr(a.iso3year, 5, 8) year, 
      min(abs(substr(a.iso3year, 5, 8) - substr(b.iso3year, 5, 8))) min_value 
    from DF a  
    left join DF b on year - year_cata in (-2, -1, 1, 2) and
      substr(a.iso3year, 1, 3) = substr(b.iso3year, 1, 3) and
      b.cata10 is not null
    group by a.iso3year
    having year in ('2012', '2017')")[1:4]
```

giving:

```
  iso3year_UHC       UHC year_cata    cata10
1     AFG 2012 0.3468012      2013 14.631331
2     AFG 2017 0.3948606      2016  4.837534
3     AGO 2012 0.3400455      2011 12.379809
4     AGO 2017 0.3764945      2015 16.902584
```

**2) Base R** This solution uses only base R.  We first create `year` and `iso` variables by breaking up the `iso3year` into two parts.  `ix` is an index into `DF` giving the rows having 2012 or 2017 as their year.  For each of those rows we find the nearest year having a cata10 value and create a row of the output data frame which `lapply` returns as a list of rows, `L`. Finally we `rbind` those rows together.  This is not as straight forward as (1) but does have the advantage of no package dependencies.

```
to.year <- function(x) as.numeric(substr(x, 5, 8))
year <- to.year(DF$iso3year)
iso <- substr(DF$iso3year, 1, 3)
ix <- which(year %in% c(2012, 2017))
L <- lapply(ix, function(i) {
  DF0 <- na.omit(DF[iso[i] == iso & (year[i] - year) %in% c(-2, -1, 1, 2), ])
  if (nrow(DF0)) {
    with(DF0[which.min(abs(to.year(DF0$iso3year) - year[i])), c("iso3year", "cata10")], 
      data.frame(iso3year_UHC = DF$iso3year[i], 
               UHC = DF$UHC[i], 
               year_cata = as.numeric(substr(iso3year, 5, 8)), 
               cata10))
  } else {
      data.frame(iso3year_UHC = DF$iso3year[i], 
               UHC = DF$UHC[i], 
               year_cata = NA,
               cata10 = NA)
  }
})
do.call("rbind", L)
```

giving:

```
  iso3year_UHC       UHC year_cata    cata10
1     AFG 2012 0.3468012      2013 14.631331
2     AFG 2017 0.3948606      2016  4.837534
3     AGO 2012 0.3400455      2011 12.379809
4     AGO 2017 0.3764945      2015 16.902584
```

**3) dplyr/tidyr**

First separate `iso3year` into `iso` and `year` columns giving `DF2`.  Then pick out the 2012 and 2017 rows giving `DF3`.  Now left join `DF3` to `DF2` using `iso` and get those rows for `cata10` in the joined instance that are not NA and the absolute difference in years between the two joined data frames is 1 or 2.  Then use `slice` to pick out the row having least distance in years and `select` out the desired columns giving `DF4` Finally left join `DF3` with `DF4` which will fill out any rows for which there was no match.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF2 <- DF %>%
  separate(iso3year, c("iso", "year"), remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)

DF3 <- DF2 %>%
  filter(year %in% c(2012, 2017))

DF4 <- DF3 %>%
  left_join(DF2, "iso") %>%
  drop_na(cata10.y) %>%
  filter(abs(year.x - year.y) %in% 1:2) %>%
  group_by(iso3year.x) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(year.x - year.y))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(iso3year = iso3year.x, UHC = UHC.x, year_cata = year.y, cata10 = cata10.y)

DF3 %>% 
  select(iso3year, UHC) %>%
  left_join(DF4,  c("iso3year", "UHC"))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  iso3year   UHC year_cata cata10
  <chr>    <dbl>     <int>  <dbl>
1 AFG 2012 0.347      2013  14.6 
2 AFG 2017 0.395      2016   4.84
3 AGO 2012 0.340      2011  12.4 
4 AGO 2017 0.376      2015  16.9
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "iso3year    UHC         cata10
AFG 2010    0.3551409   NA
AFG 2011    0.3496452   NA
AFG 2012    0.3468012   NA
AFG 2013    0.3567721   14.631331
AFG 2014    0.3647436   NA
AFG 2015    0.3717983   NA
AFG 2016    0.3855273   4.837534
AFG 2017    0.3948606   NA
AGO 2011    0.3250651   12.379809
AGO 2012    0.3400455   NA
AGO 2013    0.3397722   NA
AGO 2014    0.3385741   NA
AGO 2015    0.3521086   16.902584
AGO 2016    0.3636765   NA
AGO 2017    0.3764945   NA"
DF <- read.csv(text = gsub("  +", ",", Lines), as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. The only thing which is tricky is that I need to keep NA if it does not find any value 2 years after or before the reference year. In the exemple, the three countries had values but for others it is not the case and I should keep the NA. This has made the thing more complicated to solve..

Comment: Assuming you mean that if the input is modified to make it DF$cata10 <- NA then it should give the same output as shown except the last two columns are all NA. (1) already does that.  Have modified (2) to also do that.

Comment: I was trying (3)!

Comment: I have modified (3) as well now so all three should handle that edge case.  Also added comments at the top comparing the solutions.

Comment: For whatever reasons, 1) does not work anymore - I get a Error: near ".": syntax error. It worked before, I have not modified anything and now I have this type of error. Would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with `dplyr` only:

```
library(tidyverse)

uhc_comb = read.table(header = T, text = "
iso3 year    UHC         cata10
AFG  2010    0.3551409   NA
AFG  2011    0.3496452   NA
AFG  2012    0.3468012   NA
AFG  2013    0.3567721   14.631331
AFG  2014    0.3647436   NA
AFG  2015    0.3717983   NA
AFG  2026    0.3855273   4.837534     #Year is 2026 for the example
AFG  2017    0.3948606   NA
AGO  2011    0.3250651   12.379809
AGO  2012    0.3400455   NA
AGO  2013    0.3397722   NA
AGO  2014    0.3385741   NA
AGO  2015    0.3521086   16.902584
AGO  2016    0.3636765   NA
AGO  2017    0.3764945   NA")

uhc_comb2 = uhc_comb %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c("UHC","cata10")) %>% #pivot UHC and cata10 to long format as columns "name" and "value"
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% #remove missing
  group_by(iso3, name) %>% #for each iso3 and for each variable name (UHC and cata10)
  mutate(dist=pmin(abs(year-2012),abs(year-2017))) %>% #compute the distance between the year and the targets and keep only the lowest
  # filter(dist<=2) %>% #remove
  top_n(-2, dist) %>% #select the minimal distance (in each group)
  mutate(year=ifelse(dist>2, NA, year),
         value=ifelse(dist>2, NA, value)) %>% #infer NA if  distance is too high
  select(-dist) #discard the now useless variable

uhc_comb2 %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = iso3, values_from = c("year", "value")) %>% #pivot to wide again
  unnest #since there are several values, unnest the lists from the dataframe
```

This will output some warnings but they are not significant. I'm not sure it is possible to remove them.

If you want to understand this better, run each line one by one. Pivoting tables is a tough brain gymnastic in the beginning.

**EDIT:** this will get you the right output with no warnings:

```
uhc_comb2 %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = iso3, 
              values_from = c("year", "value"), 
              values_fn = list(value = list, year = list)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(year_cata10, year_UHC, value_cata10, value_UHC))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. The only thing which is tricky is that I need to keep NA if it does not find any value 2 years after or before the reference year. In the exemple, the three countries had values but for others it is not the case and I should keep the NA. This has made the thing more complicated to solve..

Comment: @Nellicopter I just edited my answer to consider this, it should work as you wanted.